# Large file upload to nginx fails

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. The client application uploads several image files in a POST request. The request is usually between 8M and 9M for the larger requests. I have tried multiple options including setting the client_max_body_size. I have increased the value to 300M. I have also tried some other options.

The nginx configuration file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
    server_name app.example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    # client_body_in_file_only on;
    # client_body_temp_path /var/spool/nginx;
    # client_body_buffer_size 32K;
    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8092/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

The error log is

> [error] 22959#22959: *4 client intended to send too large body: 8326396 bytes, client:

Comment: I see your config is for HTTPS, do you have a similar config for HTTP? Is the client definitely connecting to the HTTPS port?

Comment: @kristaps The client only connects to the HTTPS. I have a HTTP config, it redirects user to HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

You may be running into config scoping problems, try declaring `client_max_body_size 200M;` inside the `http{}` block. You will find it on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

If that doesn't work, try declaring inside the specific `location{}` block.

If that doesn't work, maybe there is some error in you configuration which you can check using

```
$ nginx -t
```

Try restarting your server instead of only reloading it, if there is no errors with:

```
$ service nginx restart
```

If after all that you have no success, maybe you have a problem in your API's max upload size, which varies greatly depending in your's system stack on how to fix it.